# The number of odd coefficients in the expansion of $(x^2+x+1)^n$

Tags: multinomial-coefficients

Find the number of odd coefficients in terms of $n$, in the expansion of $(x^2+x+1)^n$ where $n$ is a positive integer.

I have tried directly applying multinomial and condition for it to be odd by using base 2 but failed to find number of solutions to the equations.

Comment: You will generally get a better response if you explain how this problem came up, and what you have tried already.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to do on a problem like this, especially if you don't know how to get a purchase on it, is to systematically compute a bunch of small examples and look for a pattern.  In this case, the number of odd coefficients for $(x^2+x+1)^n$, starting with $n=1$, is

$$3,3,5,3,9,5,11,\ldots$$

(There are various tricks for simplifying these computations, which I won't into here, except to say that working mod $2$ is a good idea.)

If you don't see an obvious pattern -- which I don't -- the next thing to do is see what the OEIS has to say.  In this case you get [sequence A071053](http://oeis.org/A071053). Sometimes the OEIS tells you exactly what you need to know; other times it points you in a helpful direction; and sometimes what you find there suggests that the question you're asking is a hard one to solve.  It looks to me like this we're in the third case here.

Answer (score 2):

$(x^2+x+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}C^k_n(x^2+x)^k$ and count when $C^k_n$ is odd and the same for $(x^2+x)^k$ and it is odd when the first coefficient and the second coef are odds

All the $C^k_n$ are odds if and only if $n=2^p–1$

All the $C^k_n$ are even if and only if $n=2^p$